# "Show CPU Usage" not an option

Tags: nexus-5x, developer-options

Nexus 5X, running build number NMF26F, rooted.  "Show CPU Usage" is not an option available in Developer options.

[image: Lack of "Show CPU Usage" :(]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the current solution (running 7.1.1 build NMF26U on Google Pixel) was to completely remove the option, as the feature was broken in 7.0

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213571